# camel kafka route does not stay up

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I am trying to use kafka with camel and set up the following route:

```
public class WorkflowEventConsumerRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    private static final String KAFKA_ENDPOINT =
         "kafka:payments-bus?brokers=localhost:9092";
    ...
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from(KAFKA_ENDPOINT)
            .routeId(format(KAFKA_CONSUMER))
            .to("mock:end);
    }
}
```

When I start my spring boot application I can see the route gets started but immediately after this it shuts down without any reasons given in the logs:

```
2018-12-21 12:06:45.012  INFO 12184 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 2.0.1
2018-12-21 12:06:45.013  INFO 12184 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : fa14705e51bd2ce5
2018-12-21 12:06:45.014  INFO 12184 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: kafka-consumer started and consuming from: kafka://payments-bus?brokers=localhost%3A9092
2018-12-21 12:06:45.015  INFO 12184 --- [r[payments-bus]] o.a.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer  : Subscribing payments-bus-Thread 0 to topic payments-bus
2018-12-21 12:06:45.015  INFO 12184 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
2018-12-21 12:06:45.015  INFO 12184 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.23.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.234 seconds
2018-12-21 12:06:45.019  INFO 12184 --- [           main] a.c.n.t.p.workflow.WorkflowApplication   : Started WorkflowApplication in 3.815 seconds (JVM running for 4.513)
2018-12-21 12:06:45.024  INFO 12184 --- [      Thread-10] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.23.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
```

On the other hand if create an unit test and point to the same kafka endpoint I am able to read the kafka topic content using the org.apache.camel.ConsumerTemplate instance provided by the CamelTestSupport

Ultimately if I replace the kafka endpoint in my route with an activemq one the route starts OK and the application stays up.

Obviously I am missing something but I cannot figure out what.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your spring-boot app have a -web-starter or not. If not then you should turn on the camel run-controller to keep the boot application running.

In the application.properties add

```
 camel.springboot.main-run-controller = true
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Just curious why this approach. If I replace the Kafka end point with an active mq one the route stays up. Even more if I have both a kafka route and an active mq one then the kafka route works OK consuming messages,

Comment: Then its related to having a non-daemon thread running that activemq may have started which causes the JVM to stay up.